# Minimum prerequisites for Basic Complex Analysis by J. Marsden, M. Hoffman

Tags: complex-analysis, soft-question, book-recommendation

I want to self study [Basic Complex Analysis by J. Marsden, M. Hoffman](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/071672877X) but I don't know much real analysis and not very interested in learning real analysis. I know single and multivariable calculus, linear algebra and differential equations so is that good enough?

Comment: I would say that study or read it whatsoever, and turn back to prerequisites whenever necessary. For if not, then you may find that there will be no time when you feel fully prepared! :)

Comment: Besides I think that is a good decision to skip real analysis.

Comment: @Freeze_S I *really* don't think so. However, it's probably not necessary to develop real analysis up to Lebesgue integral for a complex analysis course. Rudin does this in a famous textbook, but I have always wondered why.

Comment: @Jean-ClaudeArbaut: Oh that was misleading, what I rather meant is to develope all the concepts directly among the complex numbers (I think like Rudin does - you mean his first book right?)

Comment: By the way Rudin is awesome! =D

Comment: @Freeze_S Analytic functions are much smoother than continuous functions, so developing everything in the context of complex analysis looks awkward to me. Maybe it's the reason I was not very pleased with Rudin ([this one](http://www.amazon.com/Complex-Analysis-International-Applied-Mathematics/dp/0070542341)). It's a very deep book, but I always feels uncomfortable with it. (for complex Analysis, I'd say Ahlfors, Knopp, or Lang are very great, and Whittaker & Watson, though dated, is excellent)

Comment: @Jean-ClaudeArbaut: Hmm, I see everything works just to good then for analytic functions and that might be confusing if you never struggled with continuity issues... By the way are you sure about the which of his books? (Rudin has this weird order and collection of topics in his books.)

Comment: @Freeze_S I'm sure, see [here](http://www.mcgraw-hill.com.sg/html/9780070542341.html) for the table of contents. I have the french translation, but it's the same. And holomorphic functions appear at chapter 10, after having developed (in a nice, readable way) Lebesgue integral. My concern is that for most purposes in complex analysis, Riemann integral is enough, and much simpler, so it looks a bit like the book is really two books bound in one. Btw, to my list I add Henrici (Applied and computational complex analysis), an incredibly comprehensive book in 3 volumes.

Answer (score 2):

Comment: I think this is good enough to get through a first course.

Multivariable Calculus: Green's Theorem, Stokes Theorem, a little differential 
forms, parametrizing curves, line integrals.

Analysis: Epsilon-Delta, continuity, differentiation, integration (& techniques), 
sequences and series.

Other: Strong foundation in proof writing, modular arithmetic and symbolic logic.

Comment: The only topics I don't know in that list are some of the real analysis topics. Especially Epsilon-Delta. I covered continuity, sequences and series already. My university does offer a complex analysis course but it is proof-based and has proof-based real analysis as a prerequisite and I am an EE so I am not too keep on real analysis.

Comment: It shouldn't take too long to familiarize yourself with epsilon-delta arguments. I also added modular arithmetic which is useful.

Answer (score 0):

The preface to the proof spells out the requirements for the reader, and indicates the level of maturity expected. The book is specifically designed for self-study, and to be useful to people from a broad range of disciplines.